# Can't Login to Web Management Except Admin

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to set up an admin user for a different virtual host and give this account management permissions to manage everything in this virtual host.

So I created a new user account with the virtual host specified with a tag "Management." However, when I try to log in to the web management console I can't seem to log in unless I tag this account with "administrator."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, right after I posted the question I found out the tags are case-sensitive. As soon as I changed "Management" to "management" I could log in.